# Is it possible using cocos2d via javascript fully?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d.
Is it possible using cocos2d via javascript fully?
I prefer to use script language to control game elements.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only languages available to program with cocos2d on the iPhone are C++ and Objective-c as far as i'm aware. (I've been programming for the iPhone SDK for nearly 2 years with cocos2d and have never seen javascript mentioned.)

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org

Answer (score 2):

This may no longer be the case as it has recently changed with the new Javascript bindings: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/wiki/cocos2d-and-JavaScript